# Power series converges, Dirichlet test

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $a_n$ be a decreasing sequence of positive numbers with $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$. Let $0<\delta<2$ be given, define $\Omega_\delta:=\{z\in\mathbb{C}\colon|z|\leq 1,|1-z|\geq\delta\}\neq\emptyset.$ Then the power series $$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n
$$
 converges uniformly for $z\in\Omega_\delta$.

I defined the partial sum $S_N(z)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^Na_nz^n=a_N\frac{1-z^{N+1}}{1-z}-\sum\limits_{n=0}^{N_1}\frac{1-z^{n+1}}{1-z}(a_{n+1}-a_n)$, with summation by parts. I also found that $|\frac{1-z^{n+1}}{1-z}|\leq \frac{2}{\delta}$ for all $z\in\Omega_{\delta}$ and all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. How can I show that $S_N$ converge uniformly? I read an answer concerning the Dirichlet test, but I don't see how this implies uniform convergence.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply [Dirichlet's test for uniform convergence](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_Test_for_Uniform_Convergence), since

- the sequence $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is monotonic and converges to $0$;
- the sequence $\left(\sum_{n=0}^N z^n\right)_{N\in\mathbb N}$ is uniformly bounded (as you proved).

Comment: How does the proof of Dirichlet's test work?

Comment: Click on the link that I provided in my answer and read the proof.